# Android shuffle Questions and Answers (string arrays)

Tags: android, shuffle, arrays

I am making an app in which there are list of questions and respective answers.
Questions are in one string array, while answers are in another string array.

I have implemented the following in a wish to shuffle the questions. (Of course the answers need to be linked to that question, else meaningless)

### Code:

```
          selected_Q = new String[totalnoofQ];
          selected_A = new String[totalnoofQ];
          int[] random_code = new int[totalnoofQ];

          for (int i = 0; i < totalnoofQ; i++) 
          {                                               
              random_code[i] = i;
          }

          Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(random_code));
          for (int j = 0; j < totalnoofQ; j++) 
          {                                               
              int k = random_code[j];                        
              selected_Q [j] = databank_Q [k];
              selected_A[j] = databank_A [k];
          }
```

The code reports no fatal error, but the selected_Q is still in sequential order. Why?
Could you please show me how can I amend the codes? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shuffle a list created using random_code, but random_code is not modified.

You need to create a temporary list based on random_code. Shuffle this list and then use it to fill the selected_X arrays.

Something like this should work :

```
    int[] random_code = new int[totalnoofQ];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < totalnoofQ ; i++) {
        random_code[i] = i;
    }


    List<Integer> random_code_list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Create an arraylist (arraylist is used here because it has indexes)
    for (int idx = 0 ; idx <  random_code.length ; idx++) {
        random_code_list.add(random_code[idx]); // Fill it
    }
    Collections.shuffle(random_code_list); // Shuffle it

    for (int j = 0 ; j < totalnoofQ ; j++) {
        int k = random_code_list.get(j); // Get the value
        selected_Q[j] = databank_Q[k];
        selected_A[j] = databank_A[k];
    }
```

Comment: Hi Junior D, thanks for your reply! i have tried your suggested advice but it still showing the selected Q and A in sequential order....

Comment: I tested this snippet with a basic java application, not an android app. Can the problem be from android sdk ? Have you tried the Collections.shuffle function on a simpler example to see if it works fine ?

Comment: thanks for your continuous advice! the above works fine now! ahha...a typo mistake in the original code leads to the malfunctioning...now it is ok!

Comment: By the way you can improve this code. Indeed, the random_code array is useless, you can use only the list. Keep the first "for" loop but add the value of i into the list.